# how to align stargazer table to the left when type="latex"?

Tags: r, alignment, latex, r-markdown, stargazer

I use stargazer package in my automated rmarkdown pdf documents to make nice looking tables. Stargazer places its tables in the center of the page, by default. How can I let stargazer generate latex code that aligns the table to the left?

here is an example of what I mean:

```
library(stargazer)

data_object <- structure(list(test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("test1",  "test2"), class = "factor"), test2 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1",        "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("test", "test2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

stargazer(data_object,title="table test",summary=FALSE,rownames=FALSE,type="latex",header=FALSE)
```

the code it produces is:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{table test} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
test & test2 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
test1 & 1 \\ 
test1 & 2 \\ 
test2 & 3 \\ 
test2 & 4 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Note the `\centering`. How can I change that without having to alter the latex code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear `\centering` is [hard coded into the function](https://github.com/cran/stargazer/blob/master/R/stargazer-internal.R#L3918). What you could do is delete `\centering` using `sub` (e.g. `sub(" \\\\centering", "", out)`).

Here's the chunk I used. I used `capture.output` to prevent `stargazer` to output what I consider intermediate result.

```
<<results = "asis">>=
library(stargazer)

data_object <- structure(list(test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("test1",  "test2"), class = "factor"), test2 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1",        "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("test", "test2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

out <- capture.output(stargazer(data_object,title="table test",summary=FALSE,rownames=FALSE,type="latex",header=FALSE))
out <- sub(" \\\\centering", "", out)
cat(out)
@
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Roman. Do you mean like this `sub(" \\\\centering", "",stargazer(data_object,title="table test",summary=FALSE,rownames=FALSE,type="latex",header=FALSE))`? That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1983395 see my edit if it helps you in any way and do let me know.